Rust cross compile aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu linker error
Hey there I want to cross compile a Rust GTK4-rs app from ubuntu x86_64 to dietpi (RPi 3b a) aarch64 but have problems doing so. I created a Dockerfile which uses the same glibc version (based on debian bookworm) and installed target libraries using multistrap. Via environment variables and .cargo/config.toml I did set the linker. Unfortunately it seems like still /usr/bin/ld is used and this is considering my target host libraries as incompatible. Do you have an idea what I did wrong or can change?
Dockerfile
FROM rust:bookworm

RUN rustup toolchain install stable
RUN rustup default stable

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y multistrap curl gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu libgtk-4-dev debian-archive-keyring libglib2.0-dev libc6-dev-arm64-cross

RUN rustup target add aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu

COPY multistrap.conf /
RUN multistrap -f multistrap.conf -d /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu

ENV RUSTC_LOG="rustc_codegen_ssa::back::link=info"
ENV RUSTFLAGS="-C link-arg=--sysroot=/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu -C link-arg=-Wl,--verbose"
ENV PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR="/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu"
ENV PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR
ENV PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/usr/share/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
ENV CARGO_TARGET_AARCH64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_LINKER=/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc
ENV CC_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc
ENV AR_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu=aarch64-linux-gnu-ar
ENV CARGO_HOME=/.cargo

WORKDIR /project/mupibox-rs
CMD cargo build --target aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu --verbose --release --bin user_interface

.cargo/config.toml
[target.aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu]
linker = "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc"

multistrap.conf
[General]
arch=arm64
noauth=false
unpack=true
cleanup=true
bootstrap=Dietpi
aptsources=Dietpi

[Dietpi]
packages=libasound2-dev libdbus-1-dev libgtk-4-dev x11proto-dev build-essential libbsd-dev librsvg2-dev libglib2.0-dev
source=http://http.debian.net/debian
keyring=debian-archive-keyring
suite=bookworm

example errors

 /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.a when searching for -lm
 /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.a when searching for -lm
 /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.a when searching for -lm
 /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.a when searching for -lm
 /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so when searching for -lc
 /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.a when searching for -lc
 /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so when searching for -lc
 /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.a when searching for -lc
 /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so when searching for -lc
 /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.a when searching for -lc
 /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so when searching for -lc
 /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.a when searching for -lc

Example rustc command from output (it correctly includes -C linker=/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc 
/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc --crate-name user_interface --edition=2021 user_interface/src/main.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --diagnostic-width
=251 --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no --check-cfg 'cfg(docsrs)' --check-cfg 'cfg(feature, values("gtk4_12", "gtk4_8"))' -C metadata=7f313cf60efc1a33 -C extra-filename=-7f313cf60efc1a33 --out-dir /project/mupibox
-rs/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps --target aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu -C linker=/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -C strip=debuginfo -L dependency=/project/mupibox-rs/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps -L dependency=/project/mup
ibox-rs/target/release/deps --extern async_channel=/project/mupibox-rs/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libasync_channel-d192101142078587.rlib --extern database=/project/mupibox-rs/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libdatabase
-4aa41cb5b2f281e7.rlib --extern gtk4=/project/mupibox-rs/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libgtk4-2267b3b90df69ab2.rlib --extern player=/project/mupibox-rs/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libplayer-da05d95bbb662a97.rlib --ex
tern tokio=/project/mupibox-rs/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libtokio-a636e1bc7f2fce49.rlib --extern tracing=/project/mupibox-rs/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libtracing-f4def53f0e0f6d87.rlib --extern tracing_subscriber
=/project/mupibox-rs/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/libtracing_subscriber-e44d3f324fc1e445.rlib -C link-arg=--sysroot=/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu -C link-arg=-Wl,--verbose -L native=/project/mupibox-rs/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/releas
e/build/ring-80943e95640185a1/out -L native=/project/mupibox-rs/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/build/libsqlite3-sys-888b81e82ba65e19/out -L native=/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -L native=/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/usr/lib/aarc
h64-linux-gnu -L native=/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -L native=/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -L native=/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -L native=/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -
L native=/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -L native=/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -L native=/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -L native=/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -L native=/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -L native=/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -L native=/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu

Any help is appreciated. Thanks upfront

I recognized the linker command seem to use cc instead of aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu. Extract of the actual (very long) linker command "cc" "-m64" "/tmp/rustcUQ0PUu/symbols.o". Why does it use the wrong linker even though I set CC_aarch64_unknown_linux_gnu, CARGO_TARGET_AARCH64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_LINKER and the .cargo/config.toml?

After several days of trial and error I found today a workaround and could create a working dockerfile to cross compile a gtk4-rs application for debian:bookworm on arm64 / aarch64. Here I share the solution
Sadly its not possible to simply install gtk4-rs through multiarch apt, because gtk4 depends through transient dependencies on build-essential package, which can't be installed in multiarch for arm64 (or armhf) and amd64. Therefore I fixed my old solution using multistrap. This creates a sysroot folder mirroring the target system. The only issue I had with that is, that the libc6 version somehow was not correctly picked up by rust. I worked around that by installing libc6-dev:arm64 through apt multiarch, which was picked instead by pkg-config. Here is my (for me) working docker image to compile gtk4-rs application. Be aware some dependencies in multistrap.conf like libasound2-dev might not be needed for your case.
Dockerfile
FROM rust:bookworm

RUN rustup toolchain install stable
RUN rustup default stable
RUN rustup target add aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu

RUN dpkg --add-architecture arm64
RUN apt update && apt install -y multistrap gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu libc6-dev:arm64

COPY ./multistrap.conf .
RUN multistrap -f multistrap.conf -d /tmp/aarch64

ENV PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS=1
ENV PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/tmp/aarch64/usr/share/pkgconfig
ENV PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/tmp/aarch64/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/
ENV PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=/tmp/aarch64/
ENV CARGO_TARGET_AARCH64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNU_LINKER=/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc
ENV RUSTFLAGS="-C link-arg=--sysroot=/tmp/aarch64"

WORKDIR /project
CMD cargo build --target aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu --release

multistrap.conf
[General]
arch=arm64
noauth=false
unpack=true
cleanup=true
bootstrap=Dietpi
aptsources=Dietpi

[Dietpi]
packages=libasound2-dev libdbus-1-dev libgtk-4-dev x11proto-dev build-essential libbsd-dev librsvg2-dev libglib2.0-dev
source=http://http.debian.net/debian
keyring=debian-archive-keyring
suite=bookworm

Running
podman build -t cross_compile .
podman run -ti -v .:/project -v ~/.cargo/:/.cargo cross_compile

